# Spring Boot - How to send an array of objects using Post request (JSON)

Tags: java, spring-boot, post

Could someone point me in the right direction as to how to do this?

I have written a separate SizeQtyPrice class with its instance variable in my Item Model. The post request works fine for sending literals but am unsure on sending objects

Note: I am not an experienced coder and completely new to Spring Boot so would really appreciate maybe some background knowledge and pre-requisite info on how to approach or point me in the right direction - (or even tell me if I am too in over my head trying to do this.)

Here is the JSON file I want to send via post request.

```
{
    "name": "Item1",
    "description": "Print 1",
    "imagePath" : "https://www.tapety-sklep.com/userdata/gfx/abb4fe9b340cb3ff7e72b89a00695b43.jpg",
    "detail": "This print is etc.....",
    "sizeQtyPrice":[
        {
        "size": "small",
        "qty": 6,
        "price": 9.99
        },

        {
        "size": "medium",
        "qty": 3,
        "price": 15.99
         },

        {
         "size": "large",
         "qty": 8,
         "price": 20.99
         }
    ]

}
```

SizeQtyPrice Class (+ getters/setters)

```
public class SizeQtyPrice {

        private String size;
        private int qty;
        private float price;

        public SizeQtyPrice(String size, int qty, float price) {
            this.size = size;
            this.qty = qty;
            this.price = price;
        }
```

Item Model declaring SizeQtyItem[]

```
public class Item implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String itemCode;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String imagePath;
    private String detail;
    private SizeQtyPrice[] sizeQtyPrice;
```

Controller Class

```
@RestController //marks as a controller class
@RequestMapping("/item") //base url
public class ItemResource {

    private final ItemService itemService;
    @Autowired //injects the service into the constructor
    public ItemResource(ItemService itemService) {
        this.itemService = itemService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/all") //get request to retrieve from backend. This is the base URL /item/all
    public ResponseEntity<List<Item>> getAllItems() {
        List<Item> items = itemService.findAllItems();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(items, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PostMapping("/add")
    public ResponseEntity<Item> addItem(@RequestBody Item item) { // JSON format
        Item newItem = itemService.addItem(item);
        System.out.println(newItem);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(newItem, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

Comment: Have you actually tried to send this json? And if you did, what happened?

Comment: From what I can see, it should be able to transform the json to your Java POJO (Item) as long as you have all getter/setters.

Comment: When I send the request I am getting a 500 error, which isn't shedding much light on things! Is there something I possibly need to do with MySql configuration? Here is my config :

Comment: # MySQL Configuration

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lanawebsite                                                                        
spring.datasource.username=Daniel
spring.datasource.password=**********
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a simple annotation issue in my SizeQtyPrice class. I hadn't annotated the class with @Embeddable

```
@Embeddable
public class SizeQtyPrice { .....
```

https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-embedded-embeddable

Edit: I also was not adding a default/empty constructor to my Item class which was giving me the following error:

```
No Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator.
```

Adding a default constructor fixed this issue and can now send post requests without issues!