# Can not store list of objects as single column JSON

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa

I'm trying to store a whole array of object into one field on my oracle database, I'm referring to the solution on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66555092/spring-boot-how-to-send-an-array-of-objects-using-post-request-json) question, but it kept giving me `Can not set java.lang.String field xxx.demo.Models.Sensors.amplitudos to xxx.demo.Models.Sensors` error, I have checked the JSON body and the entity class, but I cannot find the mistake.

Here is my code.

`entity`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SENSOR")
public class Sensor implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "TIMERECEIVED")
    private Timestamp timereceived;

    @Column(name = "SENSORS")
    private Sensors[] sensors;

    @Column(name = "LOC")
    private String location;

    public Sensor() {

    }

    public Sensor(Timestamp timereceived, Sensors[] sensors, String location) {
        this.timereceived = timereceived;
        this.sensors = sensors;
        this.location = location;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Timestamp getTimereceived() {
        return timereceived;
    }

    public void setTimereceived(Timestamp timereceived) {
        this.timereceived = timereceived;
    }

    public Sensors[] getSensors() {
        return sensors;
    }

    public void setSensors(Sensors[] sensors) {
        this.sensors = sensors;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

}
```

`Sensors class`

```
@Embeddable
public class Sensors {
    private String amplitudos;
    private Double displacement;
    private String frequencies;
    private Integer sensorId;

    public Sensors() {

    }

    public Sensors(String amplitudos, Double displacement, String frequencies, Integer sensorId) {
        this.amplitudos = amplitudos;
        this.displacement = displacement;
        this.frequencies = frequencies;
        this.sensorId = sensorId;
    }

    public String getAmplitudos() {
        return amplitudos;
    }

    public void setAmplitudos(String amplitudos) {
        this.amplitudos = amplitudos;
    }

    public Double getDisplacement() {
        return displacement;
    }

    public void setDisplacement(Double displacement) {
        this.displacement = displacement;
    }

    public String getFrequencies() {
        return frequencies;
    }

    public void setFrequencies(String frequencies) {
        this.frequencies = frequencies;
    }

    public Integer getSensorId() {
        return sensorId;
    }

    public void setSensorId(Integer sensorId) {
        this.sensorId = sensorId;
    }

}
```

my JSON body

```
{
    "timereceived": "2022-11-29T12:04:42.166",
    "sensors": [
        {
            "amplitudos": "a1#a2#a3#a4",
            "displacement": 0.002,
            "frequencies": "f1#f2#f3#f4",
            "sensorid": 1
        },
        {
            "amplitudos": "a1#a2#a3#a4",
            "displacement": 0.002,
            "frequencies": "f1#f2#f3#f4",
            "sensorid": 2
        },
        {
            "amplitudos": "a1#a2#a3#a4",
            "displacement": 0.002,
            "frequencies": "f1#f2#f3#f4",
            "sensorid": 3
        },
        {
            "amplitudos": "a1#a2#a3#a4",
            "displacement": 0.002,
            "frequencies": "f1#f2#f3#f4",
            "sensorid": 4
        }
    ],
    "location": "lokasi"
}
```

my controller

```
@PostMapping("/sendData")
public ResponseEntity sendData(@RequestBody Sensor sensor) {
    Sensor newSensor = sensorRepository.save(sensor);

    System.out.println(newSensor);
    return ResponseEntity.ok("Sensor received");
}
```

I have tried checking every possible solution and the problem is not fixed, my expectation is the data stored into 1 column for the `sensors` field in the JSON body.

Comment: can you share the full stack trace?

Comment: Don't copy answers from posters answering their own question without understanding what they actually hit and are solving. The question/answer you posted is not applicable to your question at all, and steered you wrong. Embeddable does not put the java object into a single field - what you want instead is a Basic mapping. The answer below describes using a converter to control the form the data takes in that single field and generally preferred - JPA would use java's serialization if you don't specify a converter, but you don't need the converter strictly speaking.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the JPA mapping, not with the Controller, I think.

You're using @Embeddable, which normally result in a set of columns in your main table. If it's a collection of @Embeddable objects, you could map it to a separate table with foreign keys, using @ElementCollection.

However, you want to store the collection of sensors as a single JSON string in a single column in your main table. For that, you do not need the @Embeddable annotation. You need to write a custom convertor to convert the collection of sensors to JSON.

```
public class SensorsConverter implements AttributeConverter<List<Sensors>, String> {

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(List<Sensors> sensors) {

        return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(sensors);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Sensors> convertToEntityAttribute(String sensorsJSON) {

        return objectMapper.readValue(sensorsJSON, new TypeReference<List<Sensors>>() {});
    }

}
```

Then you can use it in your entity class:

```
@Column(name = "SENSORS")
@Convert(converter = SensorsConverter.class)
private List<Sensors> sensors;
```